# angular update view model that is on repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to refresh/update a table div after uploading a file, I tried .push(data) but it doesn't seems to work also the fileUrl is in a forEach. This is the ng-repeat to get the files and render it in the view.

I'm not sure where to put the .push()

```
 var getFiles = function () {
        FileProfileService.getCVs()
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.cFile = response.data;
                vm.cFile .push(response.data);
                    console.log(vm.cFile );
                vm.cFile .forEach(function(cv){
                    cv.firlUrl =  api.getQualifiedUrl('file/'+ file.Id + "?access_token=" + accessToken);
                });
            })
    }
```

View: this is basically my ng-repeat

```
<div data-ng-repeat="file in vm.cFile">
{{file.Name}}
</div>
```

Comment: can't just down vote without any explanation.

Comment: you are assigning `response.data` to `vm.cFile` then in the next line you are trying to push same data again?

Comment: response.data is an array of objs (files), I'm not sure what to pass in the push. My problem is that I don't want to reload the page to see the a new uploaded file.

Comment: in that case `vm.cFile` is an array with the data you need, no need to push anything. Pls share your view code, what is your `ng-repeat` looping over?

Comment: `vm.cFile.concat(response.data);` if response.data only contains the new files, `vm.cFile. = response.data;` if it contains all files, old an new.

Comment: it contains all the files that's been uploaded not just new ones, but I will try to concat it. concat didn't work.

Comment: nevermind I've fixed it, I just basically need to call my getFile() func in my uploadFile() func. Thanks for the time @Jax